# Recommend different product using NearestNeighbour

Tags: recommender-system, k-nn

I am working on creating a recommendation system which suggests product for the user, based on the other user's data from the same region.

My dataset is as below

```
UserId    Product    Region    Rating
  1         A         R1        1.23
  2         A         R1        1.23
  3         A         R1        1.24  
  4         B         R1        1.45
  5         B         R1        1.23
```

I am using [NearestNeighbour](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html) algorithm to find the k nearest neighbors

First for the preparation step, I did get dummies

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

This will one hot the columns (`userId` and `Product`)

Applying NearestNeighbour

Not the exact code.. Just writing a part of it.

```
neigh = NearestNeighbors(algorithm="euclidean")
neigh.fit(dummies)
```

Getting 5 nearest neighbors using [kneighbours](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) method

```
neigh.kneighbors(input_1,5, return_distance=True)
```

I passed first row of dummies as `input_1`.

I did receive the result. But the recommendations were row index [2,3 5]

Which makes sense too. The region, rating, and product are almost the same, and hence it returns the index 2, 3 and 5.

In this case, First two neighbours were the same product(`Product A`). only the third one was the different product (`Product B`).

In my dataset I have more than 60k rows. Even with k=50, I am getting all the index with the same product.

I tried another approach,

After generating dummies, I took the first line (for input) and deleted all the rows containing `product A` related, and then ran the fit and kneighbors. - but it doesn't seem to be efficient. It's more like training model again and again for each row.

Question:

Is the approach or algorithm totally wrong? How to recommend a different product using the NearestNeighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks:

- I don't see why the user id is included in the features since the goal is to find similar products. It should probably be removed.
- Actually a different approach would be to first cluster the users based on their ratings of the products in order to find groups of similar users, and then obtain the k-NN among a specific group of similar users.
- There might be a problem here about the fact that the instances don't contain any information to match similar products. If there's a description of the product, the words could be used to find products which are semantically similar.
- Technically k-NN doesn't train a model, it just stores the instances and computes the similarity for every instance. In theory at least it can easily be optimized to select a subset of instances. It might not be easy to adapt the predefined library functions (I don't know), but it's easy to implement the algorithm manually.